# What is inside an Android APK file

Tags: android, apk

Coming form a web development background where all your files are uploaded to a server individually, the APK file is very different to me!

From what I gather it’s kind of like a zip or exe file similar to software you install on a computer, e.g. Eclipse its self. Then when installed on a device the files and folders are extracted back into something similar to the file/folder structure I was working on in eclipse. And in which case I then again have access somehow to say the /res and /assets folders once the APK is installed?

Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Android application package file. Each Android application is compiled and packaged in a single file that includes all of the application's code (`.dex` files), resources, assets, and manifest file. The application package file can have any name but must use the `.apk` extension (e.g., `myExampleAppname.apk`). For convenience, an application package file is often referred to as an `.apk`.

Comment: Thanks Android_Rocks, that's just what I wanted to here. And Android does rock. The app I'm building is to complement a jQuery mobile websites, my goal is the app will work offline when needed, e.g.. while away from home and optional updates to the database and images can be downloaded at home. Which brings me to my next question, for another post. thanks again.

Answer (score 6):

The structure of an APK:

```
|-- AndroidManifest.xml
|-- META-INF // Signature Data
|   |-- CERT.RSA
|   |-- CERT.SF
|   `-- MANIFEST.MF
|-- classes.dex //  java byte code file generated after the compilation
|-- res // resource files
|   |-- drawable
|   |   `-- icon.png
|   `-- layout
|       `-- main.xml
`-- resources.arsc
```

You can find more detailed information here:
http://android-anything.diandian.com/post/2011-09-28/5377936

Comment: Android does not run a Java VM, even though Android apps are usually written in Java.  They are compiled to bytecode intermediately, but then to Dalvik.  classes.dex is "deodexed Dalvik", not java byte code.