# Is .apk an executable or a package?

Tags: android, apk

I want to know that a .apk file of android is an executable or it is just a package that contains the compiled code, resources, manifest.xml etc.

Comment: I also want to know whats the windows 8 equivalent of .apk and is it also a package just like .apk?

Answer (score 3):

It's like Zip format and it's just a Package :

**Wikipedia** : Android application package file (APK) is the file format used to distribute and install application software and middleware onto Google's Android operating system; very similar to an MSI package in Windows or a Deb package in Debian-based operating systems like Ubuntu. To make an APK file, a program for Android is first compiled, and then all of its parts are packaged into one file. An APK file contains all of that program's code (such as .dex files), resources, assets, certificates, and manifest file. As is the case with many file formats, APK files can have any name needed, provided that the file name ends in ".apk".[1](http://www.guidingtech.com/10352/what-are-android-apk-files-how-to-install-them/)[2][3][4]

APK files are ZIP file formatted packages based on the JAR file format, with .apk file extensions. The MIME type associated with APK files is application/vnd.android.package-archive.

Another Useful [Link](http://www.guidingtech.com/10352/what-are-android-apk-files-how-to-install-them/)

Comment: So, what basically executes on an android device ??

Comment: @Mayank : Unlike .exe Android handle it for us and install it's content.i don't know exactly what happens when Android unpack .Apk and install it's content on Device ;) Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a hybrid between the two.  Code isn't executed directly out of it (the classes are copied into a separate file and optimized for your system prior to execution), but stuff like the application manifest and resources are loaded directly from it when they're needed.

Answer (score 0):

A general explanation can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APK_%28file_format%29). i also found a similar thread in SO (can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8415098/what-is-inside-an-android-apk-file)). On AndroidBook, there's an interesting thread [too](http://www.androidbook.com/item/3279): In brief, it's a package :)

Answer (score 0):

> APK files are Android Package and a variant of the JAR file format, which are built on the
>   ZIP file format, with a .apk file extension.