# What does APK file do?

Tags: javascript, android, html, apk, notepad

I have made a few apps for android in HTML and JavaScript and when I convert it to APK file, put it on my mobile phone it actually installs the real app. It happens with an app made in Java when you extract it too... According to the answers of this question [What is inside an Android APK file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8415098/what-is-inside-an-android-apk-file) it seems to me like it actually unzips the project. My questions are:

1. What does APK file do?(how does it work)
2. Is it possible to programmatically create one without using other programmes or using **notepad** only

I'm looking forward to your answers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An APK is a zip file that contains encoded manifest (xml), code binary (dex), images (png, gif), layout (xml) resources, and a few other misc things. And yes, you can produce the package by hand but it is far easier to use the available development tool to do it.

Comment: Thank you! I'll have to check how does it work. I'm not sure why exactly do I get downvotes on this question tho

Comment: I think people assume that it is such a basic fundamental thing that every Android developer should know. But with a lot of tools and different way to generate Android app these days, these mechanics are often hidden away.

Comment: Yeah maybe that's it, but my next question will definitely be about building an APK file in notepad

Comment: Lol, I wouldn't attempt to do that. There are a lot that go into constructing an apk file from scratch. Whatever tool/platform that you used to convert HTML/javascript into android apk for you did all the heavy lifting (dexing, encoding, compressing, proguard, signing, aligning etc).

Comment: Oh it seems too much for me, I'm just a self taught guy... nothing special... so I shall stick to tools I used before

Comment: Why should you ask about building app in notepad???Better ask how do compilers work. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/118587

Comment: @roostertech I'd like to ask you one more question before accepting your answer. What happens to my question when it gets to many downvotes? does it close? or I can get countless downvotes?

Comment: @MilosLulic Thanks I will check it out

Comment: @Djordje it can get countless downvotes or someone can flag it as offtopic

Comment: It would be almost impossible to produce dex files by hand, dont confuse people reading this answer

Comment: @MilosLulic Thanks bro ;)

Comment: Compiling an app(dexing, encoding, compressing, aligning etc) is done by compilers present in every IDE. Doing the work of a compiler for an app by hand would mean sitting behind a screen for the next few years to create a simple hello world program.